# How can I create a list in Google App Script to be used in an email from a range of cells

Tags: list, email, range

I am learning Google Apps Script so if there is a simple solution to my question, thanks for reading this question.
I have been able to successfully use a script to send individual emails for each row from a range of cells in a sheet. This is the script that does this. This sends an email to an individual if they have been assigned a task. The task owner can receive multiple emails

var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Code and Functions").getRange(1,1).getValue();

for (var i = 4;i<=lr;i++){

```
var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i,9).getValue();
var currentName = ss.getRange(i,8).getValue();
var currentStatus = ss.getRange(i,11).getValue();
var currentDescrip = ss.getRange(i,6).getValue();
var currentGroup = ss.getRange(i,5).getValue();
var currentNote = ss.getRange(i,7).getValue();
var currentDate = ss.getRange(i,4).getValue();
var currentRef = ss.getRange(i,10).getValue();

var messageBody = templateText.replace("{Name}",currentName).replace("{Task Group}",currentGroup).replace("{Task Descrip}",currentDescrip).replace("{Task Notes}",currentNote).replace("{Create Date}",currentDate).replace("{Status}",currentStatus).replace("{Reference}",currentRef);

var subjectLine = "Task Assigned";
```

What I would like to do is accumulate the individual tasks for a recipient and send a list in one email. The portion that I need help with is how to declare a variable for the list.

The email is created by declaring var templateText noted above then replacing the values with the declared variable, i.e currentDescrip, currentGroup ... etc. These variable are single cells. I am attempting to declare a range consisting of a variable number of rows and a static number of columns. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot imagine your goal from `What I would like to do is accumulate the individual tasks for a recipient and send a list in one email.`. Can you provide the sample email you want to send? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: Added email description as an edit

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.